# using "or" in where clause for date type column issue when compare with sysdate in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I've just created a sample table with following data:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA (  DT DATE   );
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('13-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('14-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('15-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('16-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('17-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('18-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('19-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('20-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('21-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('22-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('23-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('24-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('25-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('26-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into aaa (DT) values (to_date('27-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

commit;
```

and then the following query, returns abnormal results: (15 records instead of 7)

```
select count(*) from aaa d
where 
(d.dt > sysdate)
or
d.dt < to_date(20130120,'yyyymmdd')
```

but when I change left side and right side of "OR" it returns correct result: (7 records)

```
select count(*) from aaa d
where 
d.dt < to_date(20130120,'yyyymmdd')
or
(d.dt > sysdate)
```

does anybody know what is this issue about and how to solve it?

add: replacing d.dt with d.dt+1 is also solving this problem,

```
d.dt+1 > sysdate+1
```

Comment: can't reproduce : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6dff/4

Comment: `to_date()` expects a character literal, not a number. So `to_date(20130120,'yyyymmdd')` is invalid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oracle will apply an implicit cast, so the statement is valid.

Comment: Agree with @RaphaëlAlthaus - both queries return the same result.

Comment: @abdkok What makes you think that your query should return 7 records in any case? Considering that today is 12th of January and all of your dates are greater than that `d.dt > sysdate` as a part of `OR` condition will always return 15 records. To return 7 records it has to be `AND` condition.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin - you know it's 2014 now, right? *8-) So none of the dates are greater than `sysdate`.

Comment: @AlexPoole My bad, missed the year part. :( Although for future readers of the question would be more clear if OP explicitly specified current date for the query.

Comment: Bug 9495697 looks a likely candidate if you're on 11.2.0.1; I pretty sure I'm not allowed to reproduce any of the information from Oracle Support, but [someone else has here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1125590?start=17), and it's included in the 11.2.0.2 patch set list of bug fixes (note 1179583.1 or 1114533.1). But it could be something else. Raising an SR is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Well I am able to replicate it and the reason behind such behavior is Oracle's  interpretation of predicates.

Version of OS and Oracle where this can be reproduced:

```
SQL> host ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL>
```

In the first case predicate is modified to    `filter("D"."DT" IS NOT NULL)`
while in the second query, predicate works as provided `filter("D"."DT"<TO_DATE(' 2013-01-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') OR "D"."DT">SYSDATE@!)`

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from aaa d
  3  where (d.dt > sysdate)
  4  or d.dt < to_date('20130120','yyyymmdd')
  5  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
        15

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 977873394

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     9 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| AAA  |    15 |   135 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("D"."DT" IS NOT NULL)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)


Statistics

----------------------------------------------------------
      4  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
     15  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
    346  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    364  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
      1  rows processed

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select count(*)
  2  from aaa d
  3  where d.dt < to_date('20130120','yyyymmdd')
  4* or (d.dt > sysdate)
SQL> 
/

  COUNT(*)
----------
         7

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 977873394

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     9 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| AAA  |     7 |    63 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("D"."DT"<TO_DATE(' 2013-01-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss') OR "D"."DT">SYSDATE@!)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)

Statistics

----------------------------------------------------------
      4  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
     15  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
    346  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    364  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
      1  rows processed

SQL>
```

I could not figure out this behavior of Oracle, quite possible some experts can explain this.

Again in the third example, predicates are used correctly. `filter("D"."DT"<TO_DATE(' 2013-01-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') OR INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."DT")+1>SYSDATE@!+1)`

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select count(*)
  2  from aaa d
  3  where (d.dt + 1 > sysdate + 1)
  4* or d.dt < to_date('20130120','yyyymmdd')
SQL> /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         7

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 977873394

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     9 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| AAA  |     7 |    63 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("D"."DT"<TO_DATE(' 2013-01-20 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss') OR INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."DT")+1>SYSDATE@!+1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          5  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         15  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        346  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        364  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL>
```

Its quite obvious that the same cannot be reproduced from Oracle Version 11.2.0.2.0 and 11.2.0.3.0 on Linux servers.

**Update:**

As **Alex Poole** mentioned in the comments - "This might be bug 9495697, 'Wrong results may be returned for a query containing two OR'd filter predicates on the same column, where the other side of one predicate is not a compile-time constant (eg. It is a bind, sysdate, etc..)"

Comment: Which versions and patch level are you able to reproduce this with?

Comment: Hi Alex, I reproduced it in Oracle 11r2 version, Installed on Windows 7 64 bit Architecture.

Comment: 11.2.0.1, or patched? It doesn't seem to be reproducible on 11.2.0.2 (which SQL Fiddle seems to be running) or later. If you are on a later patch level then it could be OS-specific. Just curious really, it certainly seems to be a bug.

Comment: Hi.. Right now I am not at my workstation where I reproduced it, once I am there I will check and post. Even I tried to reproduce in 11.2.0.3 on Linux Server, there it is working fine. You are right, seems to be something related to OS or the version, I will check and post again.

Comment: This could be a very critical bug! I wonder and I couldnt replicate too! My version is `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Unix, Solaris`

Comment: Post has been updated with Oracle version and OS details where this can be reproduced.

Comment: @San - thanks for confirming; as I said in a comment on the question, I suspect this might be bug 9495697, 'Wrong results may be returned for a query containing two OR'd filter predicates on the same column, where the other side of one predicate is not a compile-time constant (eg. It is a bind, sysdate, etc..)'.