# How can the placing of SYSDATE within a WHERE-clause influence the resultset?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I encountered an rather strange situation on two Oracle 11 DB-Hosts, that i cannot reproduce anywhere else:

Given a rather simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE ( XID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
                         XSTRING CHAR(14 BYTE) NOT NULL,
                         XDATE DATE NOT NULL )
LOGGING NOCOMPRESS NOCACHE NOPARALLEL MONITORING;
```

Filled with rather simple data:

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(XID, XSTRING, XDATE)
VALUES(1119870, 'R008505       ', TO_DATE('08/01/2007 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Then this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TESTTABLE
 WHERE xstring='R008505'
   AND (xdate >= SYSDATE OR xdate < '01.01.1900');
```

Returns the only row in the table (which is of course wrong), while the following query (with the SYSDATE-line swapped) returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TESTTABLE
 WHERE xstring='R008505'
   AND (xdate < '01.01.1900' OR xdate >= SYSDATE);
```

Using `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` does not make any difference here.

How this could happen and how to fix this issue?

Comment: What patch level are you on? I don't see this on 11.2.0.3, or [on SQL Fiddle which is 11.2.0.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d646/1); both queries find zero rows. And what do the execution plans show for the two queries?

Comment: @AlexPoole Ora-Version is 11.2.0.1.0, the exection plans (full table scan) are identical.

Comment: I was more interested in the filter predicates shown in the plan really. This seems to be a bug. Looks like possibly bug 9495697. Patching the database ought to help, if that's feasible. But you'll need to raise a service request with Oracle to get confirmation that it's the same issue.

Comment: Thought this sounded familiar... [essentially the same as this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21076649/266304)?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Applying Patch 9495697 resolved the issue. Thanks a lot. In case you provide an answer i'd be glad to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21076649/266304), which is possibly related to bug 9495697, though it wasn't confirmed in that case. I can't share the bug details from MOS, but [someone else has already done so](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1125590?start=17).

As in that case, the symptoms you're experiencing on the base 11.2.0.1 release don't manifest for me on 11.2.0.3, [or on SQL Fiddle, which is running 11.2.0.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d646/1).

If it is that bug then applying the 11.2.0.2 patch set should cure it, or a patch is available for just this issue; not sure if you need to raise a service request and get confirmation that the symptoms do match that specific bug before applying the patch though.